# Converting Swagger 2.0 to openAPI 3.0 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a tool, in it I need to create the some text area, and you paste your swagger 2.0 YAML and when you click on convert, it gets converted to openAPI 3.0

And here comes my question:
Do we have any tool, library that I can use in my react code to be doing the conversion from 2.0 to openAPI 3.0 ?

I have tried using [swagger2openapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger2openapi) but it somehow does not work, and shows many errors as it is considered as deprecated

Comment: If you have a backend, you could use the official swagger.io API to convert it: https://converter.swagger.io/